# mysql replace the column with specific text based on check

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code

```
 $all = array();

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT `resume_status` , count(`resume_status`) total_candidates 
FROM `conts` WHERE `client_id` = '56' group by `resume_status`");

$all[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($all);
```

if I print $all array without encoding it in json it shows the following data

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [resume_status] => 1
                    [total_candidates] => 39
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [resume_status] => 2
                    [total_candidates] => 7
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [resume_status] => 3
                    [total_candidates] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

I am fetching multiple statuses from table against this resume_status column

if resume_status = 1 (then it should be resume_status=>'Pending')

if resume_status = 2 (then it should be resume_status=>'In Queue')

if resume_status = 3 (then it should be resume_status=>'Approved')

I have tried case statement in the query but didn't succeed. Any help will be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CASE WHEN for multiple choise

```
  $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT 
      CASE when  `resume_status` = 1 then 'Pending'
           when  `resume_status` = 2 then  'In Queue'
           when  `resume_status` = 3 then 'Approved' 
      END as str_resume_status, count(`resume_status`) total_candidates 
  FROM `conts` 
  WHERE `client_id` = '56' 
  group by str_resume_status");
```

Comment: Thanks..

Worked perfect :)